# How to disable button when check box is unchecked

Tags: react-native

I have one check-box for terms and services and one button, initially the check box will be checked but if someone uncheck the check box I want to disable the button so the user cannot proceed further, please let me know how I can achieve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Need a lot more info here (code, to begin with). But generally speaking you can do something like `const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false)`, and then update that state when the checkbox is checked/unchecked. You can then conditionally disable your button based on that state variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```js
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false);
      const toggleDisableButton = () => {
        setDisableButton(!disableButton);
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="demo"
            name="demo"
            value="demo"
            onChange={toggleDisableButton}
          />
          <button disabled={disableButton}>button</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Use Formik to build forms..